# Perl Script to grep for and string in a multiple text files and copy matching line to spreadsheet

Tags: perl

I am newbie to perl, I would like to write a perl script to read in  multiple text files and look for string and copy the line containing string to an spreadsheet.

Ex: I want to open file csv.txt and look for string "Color" in each line and copy the line to a spread sheet

> > Color: Name any color

From this line I want to copy Name any color to spreadsheet.

Thanks

Comment: You forgot to ask a question!

Comment: This question shows no effort on your side. Google 'perl file io' and then 'perl match string' or sth. like that. Also if you want to read mult. files, try searching for 'perl glob files'.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for tips on writing good questions.  Before you ask here you are expected to have done some research and tried to solve the problem yourself.  You show what you have done and what you don't understand and ask a _specific_ question.

Answer (score 2):

For starter: Read CSV file you could use Text:Csv.

http://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV

Nice tutorial: http://perlmaven.com/how-to-read-a-csv-file-using-perl

You could use simple regexp to find every line:

```
if ($line =~ m!Color!){
   #do things if $line contain this word

}
```

You could write a new excel file with this module: Excel::Writer::XLSX

http://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX

I you still have a trouble, close this question, create a new one and do not forget to include your code there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask